# Node request external API within local get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, asynchronous

I'm trying provide the response of an external API call when I perform a local GET request but struggling with how to get this to work.

My code at the moment is:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  request.post('http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=' + apikey + 
'&symbols=gbp', function(err, res, body) {
    console.log(body)
  })
  res.render('index')
})
```

My knowledge and experience with callbacks and async programming is limited, but how do I pass the response of the request POST into the GET request to then pass it to the index?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can chain calls in Express, so it's very easy to call an external service within a GET request, e.g.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    request.post('http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=' + apikey + '&symbols=gbp', function(err, response, body) {
    console.log(body)
    res.send(body);
  })
})
```

In this case we're sending back the raw response from the POST, it is easy to wrap this in another object, e.g.

```
res.send( { status: 'ok', post_result: body });
```

Comment: Thanks, got it working, just had to rename the res in the post request to response

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks can be difficult to understand, and the problem you describe isn't uncommon (it even has a name - [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/)). Partly the reason why Node introduced the `async` / `await` syntax - here's the equivalent of your code in that style

```
app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const uri = `http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=${apikey}&symbols=gbp`;
    const data = await request.post(uri);
    return res.render('index', { data }); // or pass whatever you need from `data` into the view
  } catch (e) {
    return next(e);
  }
}
```

Notice the one big difference? No callbacks and you get all the same benefits of asynchronous code with bonus of writing code in a synchronous style.